# UV map not applying to object

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

**EDIT: I found the solution using this tutorial:** https://youtu.be/8NEmx0cHwoI

I watched a tutorial on UV mapping, it didnt really help me with my issue, so here is my problem;

[image]

As you can see in this image, the UV is visible to the left, but there is no color displayed.

Here is my shader editor:
[image]

I have no idea what to do now, any help and clear advice would be appreciated.

Comment: mmh weird, either I've time-travelled or Blender Stack Exchange has a bug, have you not already asked the question? Actually you need to assign the material to your cube and also make sure that the material is correctly set (Image Texture plugged into the Principled BSDF and so on)

Comment: The previous question has been deleted by the look of it. I use a RSS feed and trying to open it in a browser gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different tutorial: https://youtu.be/8NEmx0cHwoI the one i used original was outdated.